# How to handle many answer that have the "same problem"

Tags: discussion

Recently I see a question that [Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out OR Read timed out from JCENTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333245/received-status-code-504-from-server-gateway-time-out-or-read-timed-out-from-jc) when I see all the answer they just write "have the same problem".

How to handle this problem of answer, should we just flag all the answer?

Comment: Sure. Downvote them too if they aren't useful.

Comment: This is pretty much what the "not an answer" flag is made for, yes. It's quite unique to see a question where ALL answers are not actually answers. The question itself is also kind of sketchy, it asks two questions one of which is asking for tool recommendations...

Comment: I see, this is my first times too seeing thats all the answer are not actually answer the question, seems weird

Comment: Now when all the "answers" are gone, this question will Roomba within 2 days

Comment: There is nothing weird about a bunch of people that are not familiar with the site following each other's example to do the wrong thing. That's just humans being human, happens all the time. In this case I kind of wonder if all the people were maybe colleagues of each other that were just collectively reporting results.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358183/2029983) (for those that can see it), comes across like it's someone in the customer service desk replying. Though I also agree that it's not weird to see a bunch of new users acting like sheep, there were also a few users with enough reputation that I would *expect* them to know better.

Comment: Hypothesis: Rather than have their own help desk, the people responsible for this product decided to point at SO for questions. Then this "known issue" exists, and their users are directed at it. Then they proceed to do as one does on a helpdesk ticket, provide their own information about the problem occuring.